# Laravel 5 has one relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Digging into Laravel 5 for the first time I am facing an issue I have no idea how to resolve. I have a table called **enquiries** with one **enquiry type** for each. In reverse order **enquiry** belongs to type i.e. **enquiry type**.

Below are partials to my migration classes that define these tables:

```
<?php
  //Enquiry Table
  Schema::create('enquiries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        /*
         * AutoIncrement Field
         */
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('enquiry_type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('active')->default(1);

        /*
         * ForeignKey Definition(s)
         */
        $table->foreign('enquiry_type_id')->references('id')->on('enquiry_types');

        /*
         * DateTime Fields {created_at, updated_at}
         */
        $table->timestamps();

    });

   //EnquiryType
   Schema::create('enquiry_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        /*
         * AutoIncrement Field
         */
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('active')->default(1);

        /*
         * DateTime Fields {created_at, updated_at}
         */
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have then went on to define the relationships for these tables on related models.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\EnquiryType;

class Enquiry extends Model
{
  /*
   * Fields that we can mass-assign
   */
   protected $fillable = ['name'];

   /**
    * Get the enquiry type record associated with the enquiry.
    */
   public function type()
   {
      return $this->hasOne(EnquiryType::class);
   }
}

 <?php

 namespace App\Model;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use App\Model\Enquiry;

 class EnquiryType extends Model
 {
   /*
    * Fields that we can mass-assign
    */
   protected $fillable = ['name', 'enquiry_type_id'];

   /**
   * Get the enquiry record associated with the enquiry type.
   */
   public function enquiry()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo(Enquiry::class);
   }
}
```

Now getting enquiry type with the related enquiry works but getting enquiry with related enquiry type.

Inside my Enquiry class I chose to use the type method name since it made sense saying "get me enquiry with type" than "get me enquiry with enquiry type".

The query below works:

```
<?php var_dump(App\Model\EnquiryType::with('enquiry')->get());
```

But this one doesnt:

```
 <?php var_dump(App\Model\Enquiry::with('type')->get());
```

Below is what I get from the second query:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#672
 all: [
   App\Model\Enquiry {#669
     id: "1",
     name: "Customer Service",
     enquiry_type_id: "1",
     active: "1",
     created_at: "2016-07-22 07:43:48",
     updated_at: "2016-07-22 07:43:48",
     type: null,
   },
 ],
```

}

1. What could I be doing wrong?

I have realized that the string passed to with method is the relationship function defined on that model being queried. However, if I change the name of the relationship model and query with the new relationship model name I get an exception which loosely translates to the query builder not being able to find the method.

2. Is there anything special I need to do to have the relationship defining method reflected on the queries I run against the model using the "with" call?

Your guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `Laravel Eloquent` convention:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name
>   of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id

So, in your `type` method, the default foreign key will be the following for joining/making the relationship (since you didn't explicitly provided):

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->hasOne(
        EnquiryType::class,
        'type_id', // Laravel will use this by default
        'id'      // Laravel will use this by default
    );
}
```

Since, you've a different field name than `Laravel` expects, `Laravel` is using the convention (method name:`type` and `_id` as suffix, which becomes `type_id`) to make the foreign key. So you've to tell it explicitly and in your case, it should be:

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->hasOne(EnquiryType::class, 'enquiry_type_id', 'id');
}
```

The third (`id`) parameter is optional in this case because it meets the naming convention. Check `One To One` example on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) website.